# iTunes app rejected: missing feature to deliver subscription content

Tags: ios, in-app-purchase, app-store-connect

I'm implementing the In-App Purchase feature in my iOS app for the first time. I passed all test phases correctly and I submitted the app to review, but it was rejected for this reason:

> Your app offers a content subscription but does not have a mechanism in place to support the requirement that the subscription content be available to the user on all of their iOS devices.

To fix the issue I have to:

> include an optional user registration feature to deliver subscription content to all of the user's iOS devices.

My app don't require a user registration, so I'm wondering if it's really necessary.
Assuming the answer is "YES!", I don't know what really I have to do.
After the user registration, I need to save the receipt data on my host and then retrieve the data if the user change device?

Actually I get the receipt data in this way:

> ```
> func validateReceipt() {
>     let receiptUrl = NSBundle.mainBundle().appStoreReceiptURL
>     let isSandox = receiptUrl?.absoluteString.containsString("sandboxReceipt")
>     if let receipt: NSData = NSData(contentsOfURL: receiptUrl!) {
>         let receiptdata: NSString = receipt.base64EncodedStringWithOptions(NSDataBase64EncodingOptions(rawValue: 0))
>         let transaction = GTLAppleTransactionBeanApiAppleTransactionBean()
>         transaction.receiptData = receiptdata as String
>         transaction.sandbox = isSandox
>         ReceiptService().validate(transaction, completion: validated)
>     } else {
>         receiptDetected = false
>         delegate.subscriptionUpdate()
>     }
> }
> ```

The "GTLAppleTransactionBeanApiAppleTransactionBean()" is my GAE Bean and "ReceiptService()" call my GAE Endpoint service. This service check the receipt data with Apple.

A Swift example will be very much appreciated. :P

Sorry for my English.
Thanks, Alessio.

Comment: You don't need the receipt. You store on your server the subscription info and retrieve content based on it. "This user has access to this until that date" and that's it

Comment: Was this rejected automatically by Itunes Connect uploading app process or by Apple's reviewers?

Comment: Are you using auto renewing or non renewing subscriptions?

Comment: I write an answer for all. I forgot to write I'm using "Non-Renewing Subscription". It was rejected by the reviewer. The uploading and test with Test Flight was all right. @SamiKuhmonen So I have to save on my server only the subscription date (the end date is calculated). Sounds good. :)  Just to know: Is the receipt data lost when the user change the phone (for example)?